# watch command displays different ps results than when running script by itself

Tags: bash, watch

Here's my script:

```
$ cat count_tomcat.sh 
ps -ef | grep tomcat| wc -l
$ ./count_tomcat.sh 
2
```

Now with the `watch` command it has different results:

```
$ watch ./count_tomcat.sh


Every 2.0s: ./count_tomcat.sh                                                                                                                                                                                Fri Oct 15 16:50:43 2021

5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just run:

```
watch -x pgrep -c -f tomcat
```

To regularly get a count of processes whose command line contains `tomcat`.

Or

```
watch -x pgrep -c -x tomcat
```

For the processes whose name (not command line; like in the output of `ps -e` wrt `ps -ef`) *is* tomcat.

Or:

```
watch -x pgrep -c -u tomcat
```

For the count of processes running as user `tomcat` (as it's not clear what column of the output of `ps -ef` you intend to match).

With `-x`, at least for `procps-ng`' implementation of `watch`, we skip running a shell but execute the command directly.

Note that `pgrep -f tomcat` will not report itself (even though its command line contains `tomcat`), but it would count the `watch` command and without `-x` added to `watch`, possibly the `sh -c 'pgrep -f tomcat'` that `watch` invokes to parse that command line if your `sh` implementation doesn't optimise out the fork for the last command.

```
watch -x pgrep -cf '[t]omcat'
```

Would avoid that as the `[t]omcat` pattern doesn't match itself.

(without `-x`, that would have to be:

```
watch 'pgrep -cf "[t]omcat"'
```

as `[x]` is also a shell globbing operator so needs to be escaped both for your shell and the shell that `watch` runs)

Of course, it would also match on a process that runs `vi tomcat.conf` or `atomcatalog`. Matching processes based on command line is very brittle. With `pgrep` you can add more options to refine the filter and limit the risk of identifying the wrong processes.

On modern Linux systems, you should be able to rely on control groups, or query `systemd` for that information if `tomcat` has properly been setup as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when you run a script "the normal way" `./count_tomcat.sh` it doesn't spawn a new bash process, it just runs it in the current bash process.  So no new entry for that script in `ps` output.

When you run it via watch, it spawns a whole new bash process, with your script as a parameter.  So now script shows up (itself) in the `ps` output.  So be aware with `ps` and `watch`.

Second issue: when running the `ps` command in a "normal" bash script, it knows it's being "run as a script" and does full output.

When running the `ps` command within a script being run by the `watch` command, somehow `ps` doesn't know that it's not in a TTY environment (i.e. in a script), so it truncates the output size to exactly 80.  Something's not right there.  Fix: use `ps -ww` (infinite width) iff run within watch.  Maybe there are other ways.
Weird.

Helpful is to add `set -x` to script.

Comment: That's not correct; running a script with `./scriptname` *does* start a new subprocess. Try removing the `| wc -l` so you can see what processes are actually being seen. (BTW, this sort of confusion is exactly why `pgrep` is preferred over `ps | grep`.)

Comment: OK it is a subprocess that doesn't contain the script name in its ps output?

Comment: Apparently not. This seems to be a side effect of how bash handles scripts that don't start with a shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`). Try making a script that contains just a single line: `echo "running as process ID $$"; ps`, make it executable, and run it with `./scriptname`. Compare with running the same command in your interactive shell, and you'll see that the script lists an extra "bash" process. Now, add a shebang to the script and try again. You can also try running it with `source scriptname`, and you'll see that this method *does* run it in the same shell.